# Why did the ancient Indians name Mars as "Angaraka"?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, identification-request, name

The ancient Indians (Vedic) named Mars as Angaraka which means Son of the Earth. Is there any mention of the "Angaraka" in the Vedas?

Comment: "**Angaaraka**" does not mean '**son of earth**'. "**Angaaraka**" means "***One who looks like burning coal, that is red like burning coal***". Mangala looks red so he is called Angaaraka

Comment: This was mentioned in one of the texts published by ISRO. So not sure where they referred this from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angaraka (Mars) is one of the Navagrahas. He is also called Mangal or Kuja. He is a planet of martial aspect, and the equivalent of Mars in Roman Mythology or Ares in Greek. He is red colored and is said to be a descendent of Bharadwaja.

According to the **Padma Purana** (Vishnu Purana) , once a drop of perspiration from Lord Vishnu's brow fell on the earth, and from it sprang a red colored child, who was called Lohitaanga, for his red color. Lohitaanga performed many penances and won a boon from Brahma to become one of the Navagrahas, with the name of Angaraka.

He is also sometimes equated to Skanda, the commander of the Deva army. His vehicle is the goat. Tuesday is his sacred day, red his favorite color.

[Angaraka-Mars](http://www.apamnapat.com/entities/Angaraka.html)